# insert and update in mysql table using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

There are two tables in my database (filedetails and filestatus).

I using the following code to insert value in `filedetails` table.

In `filestatus` table i have 3 columns

```
filenumber,
fdepartment,
status(either in or out).
```

In my `status.jsp` page I have given 3 dropdown list in which 2 dropdownlist take `filenumber` and `department` from `filedetails` table and 1 takes status(which is either IN or OUT).

If status is OUT values are simply inserted in `filestatus` table but if it is in the values are inserted into `filestatus` and `department` corresponding to `filenumber` gets updated.

The problem is the `filenumber`, if i use the following code to insert `filenumber` then how will i update the file number ?

Is ther some other way to do this?

file.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Insert File Page</title>
    <style>
header {
background-color:teal;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding:30px;
}

section {
width:350px;
float:left;
padding:150px;
}
footer {
background-color:black;
color:white;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightsteelblue;">
   <%
String userName = null;
String sessionID = null;
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies !=null){
for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
if(cookie.getName().equals("user")) userName = cookie.getValue();
}
}
%>
<header>
<h3>Hi <%=userName %></h3>
</header>
<a href="create.jsp"><font color="black">back</font></a>
<form action=" LogoutServlet" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Logout" >
</form>
<section>
<form action="FileServlet" method="post">
<h3>Insert File Details</h3>
    <table border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>File Name :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="filename" value="" size="50"    /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>File Type</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="type" value="" size="50" />  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Place of Origin(company) :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="company" value="" size="50"   /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>HeadOffice :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="HO" value="" size="50" /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>File Location :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="department" value="" size="50" />  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Subject :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="subject" value="" size="50"   /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>File Number :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fileno" value="" size="50"   /></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="Clear" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />

</form>
</section>
<footer>
Copyright 2008 NSIC. All right reserved.   
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

fileServlet.java

```
package bean;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
   Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
    if(cookies != null){
    for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
        if(cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")){
            System.out.println("JSESSIONID="+cookie.getValue());
            break;
        }
    }
    }       
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    System.out.println("User="+session.getAttribute("user"));
   if(session!=null && session.getAttribute("user") != null){
                String user=(String)session.getAttribute("user"); 

          boolean status=false;
    try{            
        String fname=request.getParameter("name");            
        String type=request.getParameter("type");
        String company=request.getParameter("department");
        String headoffice=request.getParameter("HO"); 
        String location=request.getParameter("department");
        String subject=request.getParameter("subject");            
        String fno=company+"/"+headoffice+"/"+location+"/"+type+"/"+fname;


        Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
        String sql="insert into files(fileno,fname,ftype,subject,company,headoffice,fdepartment) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pstmt =con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmt.setString(1,fno); 
        pstmt.setString(2,fname);
        pstmt.setString(3,type);
        pstmt.setString(4,subject); 
        pstmt.setString(5,company);
        pstmt.setString(6,headoffice);
        pstmt.setString(7,location);

        int rs=pstmt.executeUpdate();
        if(rs>0){status=true;}
    }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
    if(status){
               PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
               out.println("Values have been inserted"+user);
               response.sendRedirect("create1.jsp");

    }
               else 
              {
                  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                  out.println("failed");
                  response.sendRedirect("create1.jsp");

              }                                
    }else{
    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.html");
    PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
    out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
    rd.include(request, response);
    }
}
}
```

There is create.jsp which gives link to choose for filedetails.jsp or status.jsp

status.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>File Status Page</title>
     <style>
header {
background-color:teal;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding:30px;
}

section {
width:350px;
float:left;
padding:150px;
}
footer {
background-color:black;
color:white;
clear:both;
text-align:center;
padding:5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:lightsteelblue;">
     <%
String userName = null;
String sessionID = null;
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies !=null){
for(Cookie cookie : cookies){
if(cookie.getName().equals("user")) userName = cookie.getValue();
}
}
%>
<header>
<h3>Hi <%=userName %></h3>
</header>
<a href="create.jsp"><font color="black">back</font></a>
<form action=" LogoutServlet" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Logout" >
</form>
<section>
<h3>Change Status</h3>
<form action="statusServlet" method="post">
        <select name="files">
                <%
    try{
String sql="select * from files";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login",
        "root", "root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
%>                          
  <option value="<%=rs.getInt("fileno")%>"><%=rs.getString("fname")%></option>
<%}
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
%> 
        </select>
        <select name="departments">
            <%
    try{
String sql="select * from department";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login",
        "root", "root");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
while(rs.next()){
%>                          
  <option value="<%=rs.getInt("departmentid")%>"><%=rs.getString("departmentname")%></option>
<%}
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
        </select>
        <select name="input">
            <option>IN</option>
            <option>OUT</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</section>
<footer>
Copyright 2008 NSIC. All right reserved.                             
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I have not yet created statusServlet.java

Comment: what do you want updated value to be?

Comment: suppose the old filenumber was company/headoffice/department1/ftype/fname                                             In status.jsp if department=xyz and status=IN then I want both the departmentname and filenumber to be updated in filedetails table,new filenumber should be  company/headoffice/xyz/ftype/fname

Comment: whats the issue then? since fnumber will change if department changes, as it is already using department in itself

Comment: I don't see any update command in you code. If you want to store historical records you should do an insert with the new status and after update the old status( e.g the new record has the status 1 and the old has the status 0)

Answer (score 0):

I will seperate department into two parts like below.

1) Department from which the file is being originated

2) Current location of file.

I will use the file origin department for generating the `filenumber` and will update the current location separately (Initially the current location will be same as origin department).

***If anyone having more effective way than this, then I will accept that too.***